Problem using PathCompactPath - losing file name
Sample code:
CString strCompactedPath = L"C:\\Users\\ajtru\\AppData\\Roaming\\Meeting Schedule Assistant\\Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-Videoconference.xsl";
PathCompactPath(nullptr, strCompactedPath.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), 300);
strCompactedPath.ReleaseBuffer();

The result:
...\\Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-Watchtow...
This is not what I want! I want some of the path stripped and the start / end kept.
I am compiling with C++20, so if there is another way?
I think it is because the file name itself is so long:
Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-Videoconference.xsl
So 300 or even 500 hundred pixels isn't going to cut it.
My goal?
If the full path will not fit on the title bar then compact with ellipses. I see that 300 or 500 are insufficient.

Could you [edit] and show what you want instead of describing it?

Apparently the filename Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-Videoconference.xsl doesn't fit into 500 pixels and then PathCompactPath does this.

PathCompactPathExW() allows you to control the behavior through flags. You'll only have to figure out what those flags are, because the documentation isn't telling you.

@IInspectable Tried that. If when you read the small print it says that it will strip the file name. No good.

@IInspectable Also MS unfortunately forgot the documentation of the dwFlags parameter in PathCompactPathExW().

@Jabberwocky updated. And AI tells me that dwFlags is reserved. I just need a wider width.

@AndrewTruckle don't always trust AI, they tend to invent when they do not know. But yes, dwFlags being reserved sounds plausible.

This is the solution I have come up with which seems to work:
TITLEBARINFO tbi{};
tbi.cbSize = sizeof(TITLEBARINFO);
if (GetTitleBarInfo(&tbi))
{
    const int buttonWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE);
    const int availableWidth = tbi.rcTitleBar.right - tbi.rcTitleBar.left - (3 * buttonWidth);

    // Limit the length of the file name by using ellipses ...
    CString strCompactedPath = m_openFilePath;
    PathCompactPath(nullptr, strCompactedPath.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), availableWidth);
    strCompactedPath.ReleaseBuffer();
    SetWindowText(strCompactedPath);
}
else
{
    SetWindowText(m_openFilePath);
}

The documentation for TITLEBARINFO structure states:

The coordinates of the title bar. These coordinates include all title-bar elements except the window menu.

So I use the value of GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE) multiplied by 3 to account for:

Minimize
Maximize
Close

